# push_back doesn't work as I aspected

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

i got a strange things with vector.push_back ... 
i wrote inside a loop

```
 while(size = getSectionSize(inputFile) ){ 


  data->at(k).resize(size*3) ;
  sizes.push_back(size) ;

  cout << "sizes at k = "<< k << " = " << sizes.at(k) << endl;

  double val;      
  int j=0; 
  while(getline(inputFile,row) && j < size){
        istringstream elem(row);
        for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
              //elem >> data->at(k).at(j).at(i); 
              elem >> val ;
              data->at(k).at(j).push_back(val); 
        elem >> tmp ;                    // 4th columns to skip
        j++;
  }
```

but i got

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
```

... instead if i write inside a loop

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)                // resize vector ! 
          data->at(k).at(i).resize(3) ;
```

and then reads the the data from file with push_back the program goes fine
but if i try to write out the data i got a lot of 0 0 0 (this should be related to the fact that with resize the vector increase 2*size ... and not just size)

so I have to use the orrible :

```
elem >> data->at(k).at(j).at(i);
```

In this way everythings goes fine ! but i would understand why push_back doesn't works without a previously resize!!

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: `std::out_of_range` Is thrown by `at`, when you are indexing out of range, **not** `push_back`.

Comment: yes .. is the data->at(k).at(j) that looks not allocated ..  but how I can do ?

Comment: What are the types or those vectors (`data`, `sizes`)?

Comment: data is vector<vector<vector<double>>> , sizes is vector<int> and his size is the k size of data (where data is data[ k ][ j ][ i ]), each element of sizes contains the [k][ j ] size of data , and finally [i] is = 0,1,2